# django - relatedmanager issue - how to access third model in relation

Tags: django, django-models

i have these models:

```
class Book(models.Model):
   title = models.TextField()

class Person(models.Model):
   name = models.TextField()

class EntryBook(models.Model):
   person = models.ForeignKey(Person)
   book = models.ForeignKey(Book,related_name="entry_book")
```

I have got all books in my hand. i want to know the name of person who entered these books respectively.

```
books = Book.objects.all()
for b in books: 
  print b.entry_book.person.name
```

but i am getting:

```
'RelatedManager' object has no attribute 'entry_book'
```

if i `print b.entry_book`, i am getting this:

```
<django.db.models.fields.related.RelatedManager object at 0x10d1e8610>
```

how can i get the name of person of each book thru EntryBook?

Comment: What do you get if you `print b`?

Comment: @iMom0 if i ``print b``, i will get the title of each book. (there is unicode function of book class whcih i forgot in this post)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With your models, each `Book` can have *multiple* `EntryBooks` so you need to take that into account by using a second `for` loop:

```
for b in Book.objects.all():
    for be in b.entrybook_set.all():
        print be.person.name
```

You can see I'm using `b.entrybook_set.all()` as calling it `b.entry_book.all()` (as you have with `related_name`) doesn't describe the relationship correctly

Answer (score 2):

The problem is you're trying to access RelatedManager instead of the object. 
Try:

```
for b in books: 
    print b.entry_book.all()[0].person.name
```

Comment: ``list index out of range``